# appcelerator titanium - how do i make button text lowercase?

Tags: appcelerator

I know that for whatever reason google decided to make all button text capitalised in lollipop.

How do I set it in my appcelerator app that all my button text is not uppercase, but just however I typed it?

Answer (score 7):

All you need is to define a android values under 
/app/platform/android/res/values.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/customButton</item>
</style>

<style name="customButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Add android theme to manifest (Theme.myTheme):

```
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
            android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        <application android:debuggable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
            android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.myTheme">
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a button and depend on the system's default layout?

You could just use a View instead and listen to the click event.

You could style the view as you wish and it would look the same across different platforms.

Comment: i mean, i've already written the code, i'd rather not change all my code because someone changed a default value somewhere.

Comment: Changing of default behaviour of some components (like alert dialog, buttons, switches, date pickers, etc) is quite inevitable, especially with Android OS updates. To avoid we can use components which wouldn't change (e.g. views, labels) where possible.